# Equivalent pandas dataframe in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, pandas

Do you know what is the equivalent for javascript ? This is my code :

```
def sort_df(datas):
  df_not_sorted = pd.read_json(StringIO(datas))
  df_not_sorted["Date"] = df_not_sorted["Date"].apply(lambda dates: [datetime.fromisoformat(date.rstrip('Z')) for date in dates])
  df_not_sorted["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df_not_sorted["time"])
  df_not_sorted["time"] = df_not_sorted["time"].dt.tz_localize(None)
  df = df_not_sorted.set_index(["Bus", "time"]).sort_index()
  
  return df
```

Comment: You can use `pandas-js` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  **Danfo.js**:

> Danfo.js is heavily inspired by the Pandas library and provides a similar interface and API. This means users familiar with the Pandas API can easily use Danfo.js.

https://danfo.jsdata.org/

https://danfo.jsdata.org/getting-started

Comment: Do you know if i can use this library with Dash ? I'm trying to create a clientside callback : https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks

Comment: I don't know about this... You can give it a try.